# Frame vs Semi-Frameless vs Frameless Shower Enclosures

Tags: shower

I am considering a shower for a corner of my garage and am planning to put in a quarter-round style of enclosure.  I see offerings for framed, semi-framed, and frameless enclosures, but I don't quite understand the difference, especially pros vs cons of each choice.  Can someone, ideally with experience installing these, try and explain the differences, please?

Comment: It's almost entirely about manufacturing cost and design preference. Benefits depend on the specific situation. Your question is rather broad.

Comment: I never installed that type of shower...however if I was going to, I would look at the product ratings from previous purchasers.  Much of the determination if one is better than the other is based on opinion, but can span ease of installation to durability over time.

Comment: @RMDman: yes, it is definitely the durability over time that I am most concerned with.  It's unclear to me if "frameless" (vs some sort of frame) implies that style of install may not stand the test of time as well as a full frame install might.

Comment: Frame or no frame it is the ease of install and the engineering that will make a unit better over time.  If something is difficult to install it probably will show the deficient details regardless of price or durability of materials.